# Grafana: How to remove time range in time series Or how to remove null value date points?

Tags: typescript, time-series, grafana, clickhouse

I get a realtime time series grap, however there are no data between 11:30-13:00, how can i remove the time in axis? datasource is clickhouse.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GSNJ.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9McOb.png)

I have tried connect null values, but didnt work

Comment: What exactly are you expecting? To remove segment of time axis? You'd better add screenshot of what you have now, and what you're expecting to get.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set "Connect null values" to never? The gap would be visible then.

To get a time axis that will shorten itself based on data gaps is to my knowledge not possible with the standard Grafan Time series plugin.
But maybe there is a plugin for that...

Comment: yes i have try, but didn't work....

Answer (score 0):

You can also try `WITH FILL` modifier in `ORDER BY` clause. It may help to replace the gaps with zeros: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/select/order-by#order-by-expr-with-fill-modifier